# Create unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> with literal only

Tags: c++

In the following code, is there any way to make the third statement for `text3` compile?

More specifically, I would like to know if there is a way write a statement similar to the first one for `text1[]` that will both create the pointer and implicitly specify the size of the array.

```
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    wchar_t text1[] = L"Some text";
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> text2{new wchar_t[sizeof(L"Some text")] {L"Some text"}};
    std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]> text3{new wchar_t[] {L"Some text"}};
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Personally I would consider using a `std::wstring` instead of a `std::unique_ptr<wchar_t[]>`. If you really do need a `std::unique_ptr` then why not `std::unique_ptr<std::wstring>`?

Comment: @Galik Yes, I suppose that is an option. But how would you initialize `std::unique_ptr<std::wstring>`? Another option is perhaps `std::wstring text4{L"Some text"}; auto text4_ptr{text4.c_str()};` But that wouldn't quite be the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Galik Maybe something like `std::unique_ptr<std::wstring> text5{new std::wstring{L"Some text"}}; auto text5_ptr{(*text5).c_str()};`?

Comment: Use`auto uptr = std::make_unique<std::wstring>(L"some text");`.